# Сортировка товаров по значению

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте! Есть такой запрос, который выводит все товары:

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
 (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total 
  FROM oc_review r1 
  WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' 
  GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, 
 (SELECT price 
  FROM oc_product_discount pd2 
  WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND pd2.quantity = '1' 
    AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) 
    AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) 
  ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, 
 (SELECT price 
  FROM oc_product_special ps 
  WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) 
    AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) 
  ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special 
FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
  WHERE pd.language_id = '1' 
    AND p.status = '1' 
    AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
    AND p2s.store_id = '0' 
    AND p2c.category_id = '76' 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY rating ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC 
LIMIT 0,15
```

Мне необходимо вывести сначала все товары у которых `position=1`, а потом все остальные. Пробовал в конце добавить `ORDER BY position='1' DESC`, выдает ошибку. P.S. Подскажите ,пожалуйста, где допустил ошибку (В mysql ,к сожалению, разбираюсь так себе)

Comment: какую ошибку он выдает, так как вы написали должно работать в MySQL. (если вы его конечно не после лимита ставили)

Comment: @Mike, написал так `...ORDER BY rating ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC 
LIMIT 0,15 ORDER BY position='1' DESC`. Так не правильно?

Comment: нет конечно. у вас же уже есть один order by перед limit. хотите пресортировать, заверните в еще один `select * from (ваш-запрос) x order by `

Comment: @Mike, извините, похоже я не совсем вас понял. Пробовал написать так: `SELECT * FROM (SELECT p.product_id, (SELECT AVG(rating) ... мой запрос ... ASC LIMIT 0,15) ORDER BY position='1' DESC`. В ответ получаю сообщение: `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias `. Что я сделал не так, подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Надо было с точностью до буквы копировать то, что я написал. Вы потеряли букву `x` после закрывающейся скобки, перед order by. У любого подзапроса в from должно быть имя, вот та буква `x` и есть имя этой выборки

Comment: @Mike, исправил и написал вот так: `SELECT * FROM ( ... мой запрос ...) x ORDER BY position='1' DESC`. А в ответ получаю: `Notice: Error: Unknown column 'position' in 'order clause' Error No: 1054`. Хотя поле `position` находится в `oc_product`(т.е такое поле существует). Подскажите пожалуйста, где я опять допустил ошибку

Comment: значит подзапрос не возвращает поля с именем position, добавьте его там в список выборки

Comment: @Mike, Да действительно, подзапрос не возвращал поле с именем `position`, сейчас все исправил, но ошибка осталась та же самая( 
  Не могу понять, где ошибка. Еще такой вопрос, получается мы пытаемся отсортировать после того как мы взяли 15 элементов  `LIMIT 0,15`, а мне надо сначала отсортировать по полю `postition` в таблице `oc_product`, и потом уже из отсортированных брать`LIMIT 0,15`, или я неправильно понимаю и запрос должен работать именно так как я описал?

Comment: @Mike, может необходимо уже в самом подзапросе указать сортировку?

Comment: Первый раз об этом слышу. у вас в вопоросе ни слова ни сказано о том, что те 15 записей надо отобрать уже после сортировки. Если так, то никакие подзапросы и не нужны, ставите `position=1 desc` первым полем в той сортирове, что имеется и все

Comment: @Mike, да вроде все верно работает. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.product_id, 
 (SELECT AVG(rating) AS total 
  FROM oc_review r1 
  WHERE r1.product_id = p.product_id AND r1.status = '1' 
  GROUP BY r1.product_id) AS rating, 
 (SELECT price 
  FROM oc_product_discount pd2 
  WHERE pd2.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND pd2.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND pd2.quantity = '1' 
    AND ((pd2.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_start < NOW()) 
    AND (pd2.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR pd2.date_end > NOW())) 
  ORDER BY pd2.priority ASC, pd2.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS discount, 
 (SELECT price 
  FROM oc_product_special ps 
  WHERE ps.product_id = p.product_id 
    AND ps.customer_group_id = '1' 
    AND ((ps.date_start = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_start < NOW()) 
    AND (ps.date_end = '0000-00-00' OR ps.date_end > NOW())) 
  ORDER BY ps.priority ASC, ps.price ASC LIMIT 1) AS special 
FROM oc_product_to_category p2c 
LEFT JOIN oc_product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
  WHERE pd.language_id = '1' 
    AND p.status = '1' 
    AND p.date_available <= NOW() 
    AND p2s.store_id = '0' 
    AND p2c.category_id = '76' 
GROUP BY p.product_id 
ORDER BY rating ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC, position='1' DESC 
LIMIT 0,15
```

Сначала сортируется по полю rating. Потом, если были одиновые строки в поле rating, сортируется по полю pd.name. И уже только потом если были одинаковые строки одновременно в обоих полях то сортируеться по значению position='1'

Если интересно в книге МАРТИН ГРУБЕР "Понимание SQL" найдешь все что тебе надо

Comment: Почему-то запрос возвращает один и тот же результат

Comment: все работает так как ты написал. Сначала сортируется по полю rating. Потом, если были одиновые строки в поле rating, сортируется по полю pd.name. И уже только потом если были одинаковые строки одновременно в обоих полях то сортируеться по значению position='1'

Comment: Т.е. чтобы `position='1'` имел наибольший приоритет его просто надо  переместить в самое начало `ORDER BY  position='1' DESC, rating ASC, LCASE(pd.name) ASC` Я вас правильно понял?

Comment: да. какие значение в поле position? что нужно сортировать по результату операции position='1' а не по самому полю

Comment: Вроде все работает!) Пока ошибок не увидел, спасибо! Если, еще вопросы возникнуть по этому запросу, я смогу к вам обратиться?

Comment: да, если будет время, подскажу